# How strongly affected is the buffering capacity of sodium carbonate - sodium bicarbonate by temperature changes?

Tags: acid-base, enthalpy, buffer

I would like to do a lab regarding the affects of temperature on the buffering capacity of sodium carbonate - sodium bicarbonate in particular for sulfuric acid. Currently I have two competing theories,

a) according the la chatliers principle the increasing heat should increase the reactivity of the acid thus reducing the effective buffering capacity,

b) according to Van 't Hoff equation the acid dissociation constant should be reduced, increasing the effective buffering capacity.

can anyone offer further insight or resources regarding this, theoretical or experimental?

A lot of my information especially point B came from this post [What's the effect of temperature on buffering capacity?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/101386/whats-the-effect-of-temperature-on-buffering-capacity) I don't believe this is a duplicate but rather an extension which wouldn't be suited for that stream.

Comment: Temperature has effect on the $\ce{HCO3-}$ dissociation contant and therefore the pH of buffer. The buffer capacity temperature dependence is negligible and indirect.